# Storing data in Windows App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have made a Windows App which is a spelling game, the user has a score, for example if a user gains a score of 180 when they close the app and reopen the app the score is not there anymore. Can people please give me methods of resolving this so it stores everything about the user (score and name) in which they can later access it if they close the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Store API provides a way to write your own local data to the file system, as described here:
[Accessing application data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx)

You read and write to it just as if it were a normal file on your hard drive, you just have to use their API in order to get the file handle.

You could of course also use a web service and store the data in a database, but given your experience/app complexity, thats probably a path to take with a different applciation.